# nodemailer on azure mobile service not working

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, nodemailer

I am trying to send mail with nodemailer. The script works on local machine but i am not able to include nodemailer in azure mobile service. Added 'nodemailer' : "*" in my package.json but still not able to include it.

Logs says

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

I commented out complete logic but error was still there. Finally commented out 
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

and error was gone.

Comment: Are you using the same (or comparable) versions of `node`? Are you using nodemailer 0.7 locally but 1.0 remotely? Can you give a complete stacktrace?

Comment: You are right. Node version of my machine is 0.10.29 and on my machine, it is 0.8.28. Any idea how to update version of nodejs on azure-mobile-service ?  Or how to install dependencies that are compatible to that version. 
I checked nodemailer version and it is same (1.3.0) on both the machines.

Comment: Can't help you there, sorry. [According to the developer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/issues/346), nodemailer 0.7.1 is the last 0.8-compatible version. You'll need to make some changes to your code - nodemailer 1.x is not fully compatible with 0.x versions.

Comment: You cannot upgrade the node version on Azure Mobile Services. It has a hard dependency on 0.8.28. This dependency is being fixed in the new product, but the preview isn't yet released for Node.js and you'd have to migrate your code base to the new SDK.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this issue, you need to install an older version of nodemailer so it can work at the Azure mobile service. I added version 0.7.1 of nodemailer in the package.json for Azure, then did the necessary code changes and it worked for me.

The code changes that you need to do to support 0.7.1 are very minor, here is the full code from the documentation:

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// create reusable transport method (opens pool of SMTP connections)
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "gmail.user@gmail.com",
        pass: "userpass"
    }
});

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: "Fred Foo ✔ <foo@blurdybloop.com>", // sender address
    to: "bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world ✔", // plaintext body
    html: "<b>Hello world ✔</b>" // html body
}

// send mail with defined transport object
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
    }

    // if you don't want to use this transport object anymore, uncomment following line
    //smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
});
```

[Nodemailer 0.7.1 documentation](https://www.omniref.com/js/npm/nodemailer/0.7.1)