# Node.js Azure Mobile Services - how to downgrade library?

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services

Steps that caused problem:

- I have installed module `Nodemailer` by `npm install --save nodemailer`
- I have pushed this change to repository
- `require('nodemailer')` throws ([related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753793/nodemailer-on-azure-mobile-service-not-working))
- Node.js version is 0.8 (line `"Selected node.js version 0.12.6. Use package.json file to choose a different version"` in console lies).
- Nodemailer 1.0 supports 0.10+, but there is old version 0.7 that support v0.8
- `npm rm --save nodemailer`
- `npm install nodemailer@0.7`

Problem: Nodemailer version on server remains 1.0. Pushing version with nodemailer removed from `package.json` does not remove this folder from server `node_modules`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the Kudu debug console to change some settings.  Get your Mobile Services URL and insert SCM after the service name like this:

https://[theservicename].**scm**.azure-mobile.net

Navigate to that url, this will launch Kudu.  Select the Debug Console tab and the CMD option.

Navigate to "site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts" and edit the package.json file directly changing the NodeMailer version.

Next, navigate to "site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\node_modules".  You should see the node modules that you have installed.  Try deleting the NodeMailer folder.  You may have to restart your mobile service for the delete to work.  Warning: do you have a backup or a local version?

Restarting your mobile service will trigger an automatic download of the dependencies.